# Unhandled rejection TypeError when trying to promisify a node-mysql connection and query

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm attempting to use bluebird's promisify with the node-mysql package. Node version is 4.2.4

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mysqlClient = Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Pool").prototype);

var connectionOptions = ({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'my_db'

});

var firstPost = "some sql here";

var results = [];
mysqlClient.connectAsync(connectionOptions).then(function(connection){
    connection.query(firstPost, function(){
        console.log('i reached line 26 of a node script. a minor miracle')

    });
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I get the error

> [TypeError: Cannot read property 'socketPath' of undefined]

Stack trace:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'socketPath' of undefined
    at Connection.connect (/vagrant/spam_smasher/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:87:32)
    at Connection.tryCatcher (/vagrant/spam_smasher/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:11:23)
    at Connection.ret [as connectAsync] (eval at <anonymous> (/vagrant/spam_smasher/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:13:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/spam_smasher/bluebird.js:24:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

Why am I getting this error and/or how could I debug it further? I tried to remote debug it but am not sure what I'm looking at when I get a few steps down the prototype chain. The `Async` functions do appear to be attached to the `MysqlClient` object.

Remore debugging reveals that the following section in node-mysql's Connection.js file is throwing the error :

```
 if (!this._connectCalled) {
    this._connectCalled = true;

    // Connect either via a UNIX domain socket or a TCP socket.
    this._socket = (this.config.socketPath)
      ? Net.createConnection(this.config.socketPath)
      : Net.createConnection(this.config.port, this.config.host);
```

`socketpath` is not something you need to define when using node-mysql directly

Comment: Show us the surrounding code (what's `this.config`)?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum. Thanks for your reply. The config code is here if you are interested https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/ConnectionConfig.js but I am abandoning this problem as per my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Bluebird docs are out of date. They miss that you also need ConnectionConfig to be available and so this was missing in my code, causing the error.

I chose to abandon this problem to preserve my sanity. There is further discussion [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/929) and you may also want to check out [mysql-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-promise)